# In Python, how can I access an instance created in main module from other module?

Tags: python

I didn't know much about OOP and Python...

Here's a example about my questions:

I have a class object in my main module

```
# main.py
#---------

class MyRobot():

    def __init__(self):
        self.move = 0

    def walk(self):
        self.move += 5

    def botInfo(self):
        # In my case,
        # I can only address track.howFar to my main module
        import track
        getInfo = track.howFar
        print getInfo()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot = MyRobot()
    bot.walk()
    bot.botCMD()
```

and have another module

```
# track.py
#---------
def howFar():
    return bot.move # How??
```

I need to get the `move` value in `bot` object from `track.py`

Can this be possible?

What should I do??

----Update-----

I know this example situation is really weird...

Actually I was doing some research about [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)'s commandHandler,

please forgive me about skipping a lot of detail,

because I thought my question wasn't so related to `telegram` it self.

My apologize if I wasted your time...

Comment: ...`import` it? But `bot` is only created if you run it directly - why?

Comment: I tried `import` with another method, but all I got is default value...

Comment: Then show a [mcve] **of that**.

Comment: okay, I think I did my best to make my example to fit the rules...
It might looked really weird, but I think that's what I am dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First part would be to move `class myRobot` to say `robot.py` (or `myrobot.py`) from main.py.

Next would depend on how your program is written.  Less ideal would be to assign an instance of `class myRobot` in robot.py to a global variable which you could then reach from everything that imports that module.

Perhaps second less ideal would be to have a class variable like

```
class myRobot():
    _my_robot = None

    @classmethod
    def MakeRobot(cls):
        if cls._my_robot is None:
            cls._my_robot = cls() #cls is `class myRoboto`

        return cls._my_robot
```

from there you could call myRobot.MakeRobot() once to create a new instance and any subsequent calls to MakeRobot() would return the same instance.

More ideal solution, in the actual main function of your script, create a myRobot instance and have it passed around where it is needed.

```
def run_program():
    robot = myRobot()

    while True: #or however your script runs
        #do robot move logic
        howFar(robot)
```

Unrelated,  I would recommend always capitalizing the names of classes as by common convention that tells others that `MyRobot` is a class while `myRobot` or `my_robot` is a variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was really helpful !

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by jonrsharpe in the comments, the following will throw an `ImportError`.

```
from main import bot
```

Instead, we have to import the class *then* make the object in your new file.

```
from main import myRobot

bot = myRobot()    

def howFar():
    return bot.move

print(howFar())
```

**Output**

```
0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import main
bot = main.myRobot() # bot.move
```

---

```
from main import myRobot
bot = myRobot() # bot.move
```

---

```
def howFar(robot_instance):
    return robot_instance.move

howFar(bot) # passing instance
```